# Woocommerce Processing Email Conditional Content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a block of conditional content on the Woocommerce processing email template, which normally would be easy, however, our issue lies in the fact that the client uses Woocommerce Deposits.

Here is the scenario:

Our client uses Woocommerce Deposits to allow multiple payments to be made on one product. Each time a payment is made, the system sends out a processing email. The client originally wanted a block of text added to the first email that goes out, but not any of the subsequent emails.

The original solution was to create (or re-purpose) a conditional that checks the product quantity in the cart, and then echoes the content if there is a product present. The developer who customized the site had left some code that we decided to test for this, and for the moment it seemed to work.

Here is the code:

```
$items = $order->get_items();
if (!empty($items['item_meta']['_original_order_id'][0])) {
echo ''; 
} else { 
echo 'Content' };
```

But recently this seems to have stopped working, which I'm guessing is because we're not using the right code.

So right now we're looking for either the correct code used to accomplish this or another conditional we could use.

Edit: This is the original code we tried to adapt this conditional from

```
<?
$items = $order->get_items();
$typeofpayment = sprintf( 'registration');
$origordernumber = "none";
$subject = sprintf( 'Thank You for Your Trip Payment');

if ( is_array( $items ) ) {

foreach( $items as $item ) {

if (!empty($item['item_meta']['_original_order_id'][0])) {

$origordernumber = $item['item_meta']['_original_order_id'][0];

$typeofpayment = sprintf( 'payment');

 } }}?>
```

Comment: Sorry to tell you this, but your question is very unclear as it is. Here are some remarks: 

**First:** Please What version of WooCommerce are you using?… 

**Second:** As an Order can have multiple items you need to use a **`foreach`** loop with **`$order->get_items();`** … 

**Third:** **`$items['item_meta']`** can't exist as all order items array have one or many Item IDs as **`key`** but not any **`'item_meta'`** …

Comment: Please, you should better give the complete code for your customized processing email template or/and any useful code where you want to use a custom conditional, explaining what do you need to achieve clearly.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is Woocommerce Version 2.6.14 (we have yet to upgrade because 3.1 broke the system on our dev site), and thank you for the input on the other items.

Comment: I also added the original code we adapted the conditional from. It's used to replace the subject of the email after the first has been sent out, but I'm not sure if it would work for doing conditional content within the processing email template.